# Error in python while trying to send emails using SMTP

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I was unable to find an answer to this error on the existing questions so here it goes.
I'm trying to send an email to a list of email addresses imported from an CSV file using Python, gmail and the smtplib library.
This is the code:

```
import smtplib
import csv

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

MY_ADDRESS = 'myemailaddress'
PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

def get_contacts(filename):
    """
    Return email addresses read from a file specified by filename.
    """

    emails = []
    with open(filename, newline='') as contacts_file:
        emailreader = csv.reader(contacts_file, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for a_contact in emailreader:
            emails.append(a_contact)
    return emails


def main():
    emails = get_contacts('mycontacts.csv') # read contacts
    message_template = """Test message goes here"""

    # set up the SMTP server
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(MY_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)

    # For each contact, send the email:
    for email in zip(emails):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()       # create a message

        # add in the actual person name to the message template
        message = message_template

        # Prints out the message body for our sake
        print(message)

        # setup the parameters of the message
        msg['From']=MY_ADDRESS
        msg['To']=email
        msg['Subject']="This is TEST"

        # add in the message body
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

        # send the message via the server set up earlier.
        s.send_message(msg)
        del msg

    # Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection
    s.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_mail.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "py_mail.py", line 51, in main
    s.send_message(msg)
  File "/home/hugo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 942, in send_message
    to_addrs = [a[1] for a in email.utils.getaddresses(addr_fields)]
  File "/home/hugo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/email/utils.py", line 112, in getaddresses
    all = COMMASPACE.join(fieldvalues)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

It looks to me like the error occurs while trying to read an email from the email list but I can't figure it out to be honest.
Any help or links to a related answer is welcome.

UPDATE: I was using zip because that's what the original script did (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/send-emails-using-code-4fcea9df63f). After removing it the error went away but a new one appeared: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found` My only problem now is how to change my emails list to an acceptable input for smtplib

Comment: Your problem seems to be here `for email in zip(emails):`. The `zip` function takes an iterable and return a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks yorodm that fixed that error! Now however I'm getting the "expected str, list found" error.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain **why** you use ` zip(emails)` at all.

Comment: Done, I was using it because that's what the original script did. I changed mine to accept a csv file with the emails and a string as a message but still having troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `for email in zip(emails)` to `for email in emails`.